How to create dynamic and repeatable tables based on a list in Excel 365?
I am re-vamping a series of trackers for my job. They contain month-to-date and year-to-date amounts of accounts we review in various reports.  Some of us have 2-4 reports to review, others have 3-6 reports to review, and it all varies on frequency of said reports being generated.
Each tab of these trackers is for a specific employee. In each tab are a series of 13 tables. For all tables, the rows are labeled by report on the left. For the first 12 tables, columns are the days of each month. On the rightmost column, we get the MTD tally of all reviewed accounts for each report. For the final table, we just have a couple of columns that tally up every report's MTD to generate a YTD total.
The layout looks great, but there are some issues in having to edit these.
Is it possible to instead create this dynamically in Excel? Perhaps on the last tab of the spreadsheet, there can be a series of lists - the name of each employee, and the name of any reports under their name.  This can be added or removed, and the reports will dynamically be added to each table without overlapping one another (so if two rows are added to one person's monthly tables, they'll be added without overwriting any tables underneath? I want to be able to manually type in numbers, I tried a pivot table but it doesn't seem to work here as if I try to edit values, I get an error. Unless I'm missing something?
